# Looking for advice on non_commutative ring theory: what is the successor subject, and textbook-recommendation?

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, noncommutative-algebra

I plan to study non-commutative ring theory this semester, and here are two questions:

1. What is the successor subject of non-commutative ring theory, like algebraic number theory and algebraic geometry is "after" commutative algebra? Here non-commutative ring theory means what is covered, for example, by *Rings and Categories of Modules*, Kent R. Fuller (GTM 13) and *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings*, Lam (GTM 131).
2. What textbook do you recommend for non-commutative ring theory? How do you like *Rings and Categories of Modules*, Kent R. Fuller (GTM 13) and *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings*, Lam (GTM 131)? Are they good materials for students who want to self-study non-commutative ring theory?

Comment: Noncommutative rings are quite general so you can go a lot of different places. You could study Banach algebras, $C^{\ast}$-algebras, representation theory of associative algebras (itself absurdly general), quiver algebras, group algebras, Hochschild (co)homology, noncommutative geometry...

Comment: Generally, I do not work with noncommutative rings. Occasionally, I have need for them. When I do, the two books you mention are my main references. They are both excellent. As for a following course, module theory or representation theory would seem natural. Lam has a very nice book, *Lectures on Modules and Rings,* which covers a lot of module theory as well as rings of quotients, quasi-Frobenius rings, and the Morita duality theory, all fascinating in their own right. Others with more experience in the area can probably give you additional advice. See Qiaochu's comment for example.